# How to add the Copy Bundle Resources phase with CMake in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake

I have a CMake (3.12.2) project that generates an iOS Xcode project. And I managed to configure almost everything I need via CMake, except one thing: the **Copy Bundle Resources** phase.

I can't find any info on how to do this, though this is a common task. And I can't just leave it and add this phase manually every time I re-generate my project.

What to do? Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 4):

set(png_path "${YOUR_PNG_DIR}/test.png")

target_sources(${TARGET} PUBLIC ${png_path})

set_source_files_properties(${png_path} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)

YOUR_PNG_DIR can be a cmake macro

Comment: Note that I'm getting the following warning with your code:

"Policy CMP0076 is not set: target_sources() command converts relative paths
  to absolute.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0076" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning."

You can get rid of the error by changing "PUBLIC" to "PRIVATE".

Answer (score 3):

keyword: **RESOURCE**

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RESOURCE.html

> add_executable(ExecutableTarget   addDemo.c   resourcefile.txt
> appresourcedir/appres.txt )
>
> target_link_libraries(ExecutableTarget heymath mul)
>
> set(RESOURCE_FILES   resourcefile.txt   appresourcedir/appres.txt )
>
> set_target_properties(ExecutableTarget PROPERTIES   MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
> MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER org.cmake.ExecutableTarget   RESOURCE
> "${RESOURCE_FILES}" )